# I want to delete slider revolution - where's it located in?

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

I want to delete Slider Revolution from a theme.  As you can see in the picture, the shortcode is still shown and I don't know from where I can access to that.

[image: a busy cat]

I've searched all the .php files for "rev_slider" and 0 match found.

```
<div class="wrapper uk-offcanvas-content">
  <div class="page-top-slider">
    [rev_slider laundry]
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where does it come to the homepage?

Comment: Slider revolution is a plugin.  Uninstall the plugin and then remove any shortcode references from the pages / posts you've created.

Answer (score 1):

You have to go EDIT the page.
You will have two probable paths:

1 - Through the Shortocode inserted in POST, in this case just delete.
2 - In the configuration of the page, where you ask for the slider of this page.

I am without RevoSlider, so I can not send print.

If you do not see the option in the page edit, click on "Screen Options", select the Revolution Slider, then do item 2 of this answer that I sent.

Answer (score 0):

The shortcode is put by wordpress at runtime, so if you simply change class="page-top-slider" into class="page-top-slider_temp" you shouldn't see the slider because wordpress can't know where to put the shortcode. You can remove the plugin from the plugin manager of WP or search the string into the database and remove it from there

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue and fixed it, follow the steps below:

1. Delete the exact slider which was showing on the homepage before.
2. Deactivate and delete the Slider Revolution plugin.
3. After that re-install the plugin.

The code will automatically be removed from the home page as the theme won't find any slider of that name.